# Issue with Installation of MacPorts on macOS Ventura : error of compilation

Tags: macos, command-line, install, ventura, macports

I am trying to compile `MacPorts 2.8` for macOS `Ventura 13.1` from the tar.gz achive (`PKG` installation failed).

After the `./configure` execution, I type "make" and then, I get this error that I can't get to fix :

```
In file included from access.c:36:
In file included from ./darwintrace.h:40:
In file included from /usr/local/include/pthread.h:55:
In file included from /usr/local/include/_types.h:27:
In file included from /usr/local/include/sys/_types.h:33:
/usr/local/include/machine/_types.h:34:10: fatal error: 'arm/_types.h' file not found
#include "arm/_types.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [<builtin>: access.o] Error 1
```

I have installed the last CommandLineTools of Ventura, I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SOLUTION :**

Fixed by specifying :

```
export CFLAGS="-isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk"
export CCFLAGS="-isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk"
export CXXFLAGS="-isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk"
export CPPFLAGS="-isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk"
```